# How to set scroll bar visibility to true within a custom style

Tags: android, android-layout

This is how I set up my scroll bar. I insert this attribute in my `listView`.

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroll_style_custom"
```

Then I customize the scrollbar with a `custom_scrollbar_style.xml` in my drawables

```
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:endColor="#FF3401"
    android:centerColor="#ff5c33"
    android:startColor="#FF3401" />

<corners android:radius="8dp" />
<size android:width="20dp"/>
<padding
    android:left="0.5dp"
    android:right="0.5dp" />
```

Now how do I set scroll bar visibility to true with my xml file?

Basically I want the equivalent of this but with a custom style

```
listView.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);
```

Or is this only possible by setting another attribute in the list view?

Comment: can you post a picture what you want?

Comment: The scroll bar is not visible unless I scroll the list or I use `listView.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);`

Comment: I think this is only possible setting an attribute in the list view, or using Java.

Comment: have you tried `android:scrollbars="vertical"`

Comment: add to your xml code <shape android:visible="true"/> and tell me if works

Comment: @piotrek1543 No, it's not working. It also doesn't make sense because all my xml is already inside the <shape></shape> tag

Comment: sorry i didn't see in your code <shape>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now the best way is to use `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` in xml which is equivalent to `ScrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);` in java code.

If both of them doesn't work, you can instead of them use `android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"`

Hope it help

Comment: So what is the difference with `listView.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);`?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(boolean)

Comment: I see. so fast scroller is just a faster version of the standard scroller?